# How to analyse recorded audio on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, audio

I would like to take a sample from the mic and only tell some basic stuff about it, for example:
 - general pitch
 - volume of the recording
 - maybe some other basic stuff about the waveform

How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Heard of https://github.com/TheAmazingAudioEngine ?

Comment: You could also try C based libraries such as [aubio](http://aubio.org/) for pitch and [libxtract](http://libxtract.sourceforge.net/index.html) for more complex MIR calculations